# Вытащить числа из строки файла

Tags: python, файлы

У меня есть входной файл где в одной строчке записаны числа 1 3 5 4  разделенные пробелом, как мне используя Python вытащить эти числа по одному, чтобы внести их в список? Потому что при использование append в список добавляется вся строка файла

```
d = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for i in range(4):
        d.append(f.read().split())
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    d = f.read().split()
print(d)

['1', '3', '5', '4']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

```
d = []

with open('input.txt') as f:
    file_input = f.read().split()
    for i in file_input:
        try:
            d.append(int(i))
        except:
            pass
print(d)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает